# Removing form id using inspect element removes Jquery validations

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I am using `PHP codeigniter` framework. I used `jQuery validations` like below

```
$('#form_id').validate({
   rules here,
   messages here
});
```

I have question related to security. If I remove form id by inspect element then jquery validations dont run. I know it can be handle by using client side validations. but just thinking if there is any other solution so user can not remove form id

Comment: data must be sanitized and validated server-side. Always. Validating data client-side is a nice tool in order to display the errors to the user faster, but never trust this 'validated' data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to stop someone from deleting the HTML, but you could check to see if the Form ID and Inputs are there first, before the rest of your validations..

Something like:

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
  if ($(this).attr("id") != 'form_id') {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Missing or Altered Form ID");
  } 
  if (this.FirstName === undefined) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Missing Input Fields");
  }
});
```

**FirstName is the name of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
```

Answer (score 1):

Of cause client side validation is must but when it comes to the "Security" do not trust the user. As you mentioned user can send the any data as validated data. So the best solution is to validate the same data in the back-end/ server side validation.

In Codeigniter comes with nice validation library you can see [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

For your point

> is any other solution so user can not remove form id

by assuming you are asking this related to Java-scripts the answer is NO. Because Java-script runs on the client side / on the users browser and there are ways to change or remove the form ID so that we are out of reach controlling the user editing the our script so we cannot assure what we are getting from the user and the solution is do the back-end validation as I mentioned above and hope this will helps.